# My keyboard write double qoutes " insted of @

Tags: keyboard

my keyboard write " insted of @

it will be Clear in this img

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the wrong keyboard layout. British has the double quote mark above the 2. US has it over near the Enter key

Comment: for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure I want to copy that picture in. I saw a mention of the GFDL on the Wikipedia page under it, and didn't really feel like touching the licensing subject with a stick. (On a second look, it also does say CC BY-SA 3.0, but that's still not the same as what SE advertises user contributions are licensed under, so, yeah.)

Comment: Thank you mr roaima